# Rendering EMF+ images using JS

Tags: javascript, php, image

How to get the browser to display [EMF+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile) images?

I'm open for solutions that suggest conversion either in front end or using a back end script.

But front end is preferred.

Comment: Electromagnetic Force???

Comment: Probably synonym for "Epithalamus Malfunctioning" too ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Well .NET has built in support for them, so a c# backend solution would be a few lines of code to convert to another (browser friendly) format

Comment: @Stave - PHP Image Magic  library supports "Electromagnetic Force"

Comment: Ha, thats good to know. Glad you found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EMF+ files can be converted to raster images using [PHP Image Magic (native) library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

```
$image = new Imagick();    
$image->setresolution(600, 600);    
$image->readimage($filename);    
$image->resizeImage(1500,0,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);    
$image->setImageFormat('jpg');    
$image->writeImage("name.jpg");
```

Use this as a back end service to convert EMF+ images.